# Improper integral of $\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{t}{e^{2\pi t}-1}dt$

Tags: improper-integrals

I'm having trouble calculating $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{t}{e^{2\pi t}-1}dt}$$ I tried with substitution but I get to a point where I must calculate $$\int_{1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{\ln(y)}{y^2-y}}dy$$ and I still having the same problem.
Any ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what substitution did you use?

Comment: I used $y=e^{2\pi t}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redacting **@achille hui**'s hint :

For $a>0\ ,\displaystyle \int_0^\infty te^{-ant}dt=\underbrace{\bigg[\frac{-te^{-ant}}{an}\bigg]_0^\infty}_{0}+\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-ant}}{an}dt=\bigg[\frac{-e^{-ant}}{a^2n^2}\bigg]_0^\infty=\frac 1{a^2n^2}$

$\displaystyle f_N(t)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^N te^{-ant}=te^{-at}\frac{1-e^{-a(N+1)t}}{1-e^{-at}} \to\frac{t}{e^{at}-1}$ when $N\to\infty$ for any $t>0$.

Since $te^{-ant}\ge 0$ then $f_N\nearrow$ and we can apply monotone convergence theorem.

$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \frac {tdt}{e^{at}-1}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{a^2n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6a^2}$

Comment: You don't need MCT since it is obvious that $$ \int_0^\infty te^{-at}\frac{e^{-a(N+1)t}}{1-e^{-at}}dt \le \sup_x |\frac{x e^{-ax} }{1-e^{-ax}}| \int_0^\infty e^{-a(N+1)t} dt \to 0$$

Answer (score 4):

If you expand $\frac{1}{e^{2\pi t}-1}$ as a geometric series, you may check that:

$$ I = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t\,dt}{e^{2\pi t}-1} =\sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{0}^{+\infty}t e^{-2n\pi t}\,dt=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{4\pi^2 n^2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}s e^{-s}\,ds$$
hence:
$$ I = \frac{1}{4\pi^2}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\zeta(2)}{4\pi^2} = \color{red}{\frac{1}{24}}.$$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> It's amusing to recognize this integral as an application of
>   [Abel-Plana Formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10.E2):

\begin{align}
&\lim_{N \to \infty}\pars{\sum_{n = 0}^{N}n - \int_{0}^{N}t\,\dd t - {1 \over 2}\, \times 0 - {1 \over 2}\,N} = -
2\int_{0}^{\infty}{\Im\pars{0 + \ic t} \over \expo{2\pi t} - 1}\,\dd t +
{1 \over 2}\,B_{2}
\end{align}
where $\ds{B_{s}}$ is a [Bernoulli Number](http://dlmf.nist.gov/24.2.T1). Note that $\ds{B_{2} = 1/6}$.

---

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}{t \over \expo{2\pi t} - 1}\,\dd t =
{1 \over 4}\,B_{2} = {1 \over 4}\times{1 \over 6} = \bbx{1 \over 24}
$$